# change selectbox options and the options text by another selectbox

Tags: javascript

I got HTML form with 2 selectbox, one for design and one for color.
I need that the color options display by the selected design options, in addition I need to sanitize the color options text.
And the most important thing - the HTML shouldn't be changed.
I managed to do it, but it's only work once. the colorOption innetText keep changing although I'm pushing his elements to another array.

HTML

```
<form action="index.html" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="design">Design:</label>
    <select id="design" name="user_design">
      <option>Select Theme</option>
      <option value="js puns">Theme - JS Puns</option>
      <option value="heart js">Theme - I &#9829; JS</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="colors-js-puns" class="">
    <label for="color">Color:</label>
    <select id="color">
      <option value="cornflowerblue">Cornflower Blue (JS Puns shirt only)</option>
      <option value="darkslategrey">Dark Slate Grey (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
      <option value="gold">Gold (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
      <option value="tomato">Tomato (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option>
      <option value="steelblue">Steel Blue (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
      <option value="dimgrey">Dim Grey (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
    </select>
  </div>       
</form>
```

JS

```
var sanitizeStr = function(str) {
    var regex = /\(+.+\)/;
    var substr = str.match(regex);
    str = str.replace(' ' + substr, '');
    return str;
};

var getTshirtDesign = function() {
    var design = document.getElementById('design');
    var colorDiv = document.getElementById('colors-js-puns');
    var color = document.getElementById('color');
    var colorOptions = document.querySelectorAll('#color option');
    var display;
    // Hide color label and select
    colorDiv.style.display = 'none';
    console.log(colorOptions);
    design.onchange = function() {
        console.log(colorOptions);
        display = [];
        color.innerHTML = '';
        if (this.value === 'Select Theme') {
            colorDiv.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            colorDiv.style.display = 'block';
            // Finds the colorOptions elements that contains part of the selected option text and push them to display
            for (var i = 0; i < colorOptions.length; i++) {
                if (colorOptions[i].innerText.indexOf(this.selectedOptions[0].text.substr(8)) > -1) {
                    display.push(colorOptions[i]);
                }
            }
            // Sanitize the innerText of the display elements and append them to color
            for (i = 0; i < display.length; i++) {
                display[i].innerText = sanitizeStr(display[i].innerText);
                color.appendChild(display[i]);
            }
        }
    };
};
getTshirtDesign();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Liad91/cenaejhn/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is the fact that the `color` `div` `innerHTML` is being wiped on change. You lose the full data list of colors when this happens. I got around this issue by manually specifying a new `colorOptionsValues` object and populating the color select boxes from that. See my snippet:

```js
var sanitizeStr = function(str) {
    var regex = /\(+.+\)/;
    var substr = str.match(regex);
    str = str.replace(' ' + substr, '');
    return str;
};

var colorOptionsValues = {
  "cornflowerblue" : "Cornflower Blue (JS Puns shirt only)", 
  "darkslategrey" : "Dark Slate Grey (JS Puns shirt only)", 
  "gold" : "Gold (JS Puns shirt only)", 
  "tomato" : "Tomato (I ♥ JS shirt only)", 
  "steelblue" : "Steel Blue (I ♥ JS shirt only)", 
  "dimgrey" : "Dim Grey (I ♥ JS shirt only)"
};

var getTshirtDesign = function() {
    var design = document.getElementById('design');
    var colorDiv = document.getElementById('colors-js-puns');
    var color = document.getElementById('color');
    var colorOptions = document.querySelectorAll('#color option');
    var display;
    // Hide color label and select
    colorDiv.style.display = 'none';
    design.onchange = function() {
        display = [];
        color.innerHTML = '';
        if (this.value === 'Select Theme') {
            colorDiv.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            colorDiv.style.display = 'block';
          
            // Finds the colorOptions elements that contains part of the selected option text and push them to display
          for (var key in colorOptionsValues) {
            if (colorOptionsValues.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              if (colorOptionsValues[key].indexOf(this.selectedOptions[0].text.substr(8)) > -1) { 
                
                    display.push(key);
              }
            }
           }
          //console.log(display);
            // Sanitize the innerText of the display elements and append them to color
            for (i = 0; i < display.length; i++) {
                var sanitizedValue = sanitizeStr(colorOptionsValues[display[i]]);
              var optionNode = document.createElement("OPTION");
              optionNode.value = display[i];
              optionNode.text = sanitizedValue;
              color.appendChild(optionNode);
            }
        }
    };

};

getTshirtDesign();
```

```html
<form action="index.html" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="design">Design:</label>
    <select id="design" name="user_design">
      <option>Select Theme</option>
      <option value="js puns">Theme - JS Puns</option>
      <option value="heart js">Theme - I &#9829; JS</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="colors-js-puns" class="">
    <label for="color">Color:</label>
    <select id="color">
      <option value="cornflowerblue">Cornflower Blue (JS Puns shirt only)</option>
      <option value="darkslategrey">Dark Slate Grey (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
      <option value="gold">Gold (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
      <option value="tomato">Tomato (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option>
      <option value="steelblue">Steel Blue (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
      <option value="dimgrey">Dim Grey (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
    </select>
  </div>       
</form>
```

Option 2

```js
var sanitizeStr = function(str) {
    var regex = /\(+.+\)/;
    var substr = str.match(regex);
    str = str.replace(' ' + substr, '');
    return str;
};

var colorOptions = document.querySelectorAll('#color option');
var colorOptionsValues = {};
function initializeColors(){
  for (i = 0; i < colorOptions.length; ++i) {
    colorOptionsValues[colorOptions[i].value] = colorOptions[i].text;
  }
}

var getTshirtDesign = function() {
    var design = document.getElementById('design');
    var colorDiv = document.getElementById('colors-js-puns');
    var color = document.getElementById('color');
    var display;
    // Hide color label and select
    colorDiv.style.display = 'none';
    design.onchange = function() {
        display = [];
        color.innerHTML = '';
        if (this.value === 'Select Theme') {
            colorDiv.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            colorDiv.style.display = 'block';
          
            // Finds the colorOptions elements that contains part of the selected option text and push them to display
          for (var key in colorOptionsValues) {
            if (colorOptionsValues.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              if (colorOptionsValues[key].indexOf(this.selectedOptions[0].text.substr(8)) > -1) { 
                
                 display.push(key);
              }
            }
           }
          //console.log(display);
            // Sanitize the innerText of the display elements and append them to color
            for (i = 0; i < display.length; i++) {
                var sanitizedValue = sanitizeStr(colorOptionsValues[display[i]]);
              var optionNode = document.createElement("OPTION");
              optionNode.value = display[i];
              optionNode.text = sanitizedValue;
              color.appendChild(optionNode);
            }
        }
    };

};

initializeColors();
getTshirtDesign();
```

```html
<form action="index.html" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="design">Design:</label>
    <select id="design" name="user_design">
      <option>Select Theme</option>
      <option value="js puns">Theme - JS Puns</option>
      <option value="heart js">Theme - I &#9829; JS</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div id="colors-js-puns" class="">
    <label for="color">Color:</label>
    <select id="color">
      <option value="cornflowerblue">Cornflower Blue (JS Puns shirt only)</option>
      <option value="darkslategrey">Dark Slate Grey (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
      <option value="gold">Gold (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
      <option value="tomato">Tomato (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option>
      <option value="steelblue">Steel Blue (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
      <option value="dimgrey">Dim Grey (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
    </select>
  </div>       
</form>
```

Comment: thank you!, it fix the issue, and I guess that I could also check for the design value and append the colors options by theirs values, but the main reason I didn't went that way is what if in the future the color selectbox will contain more then 100 options? I'm trying to understand why the colorOptions elements innerText is changing while I'm changing the display elements innerText. when I'm use the push method isn't it create a copy the object to the display array?

Comment: @LiadIdan I have added another code snippet with a more robust solution that iterates through the `#color` options and generates the data object. Won't matter if there are 6 or 100 options in the select box now.